# Compact closed aspherical manifolds with vanishing second homology in all the covering spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

I wonder if there exists a compact closed smooth aspherical manifold $M$ of dimension at least $4$, so that for any covering space $\tilde{M}$ over $M,$ we always have $H_2(\tilde{M},\mathbb{Z})=0$ and $H_2(\tilde{M},\mathbb{Z}/v\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all integers  $v\ge 2$.

Of course, when $H_2$ is replaced with $H_1,$ then the answer is negative since we can always choose a covering with homotopy type of $S^1$. If we drop the closedness assumption, the answer is true by considering a regular neighborhood of a bouquet of circles in $\mathbb{R}^4.$

The motivation comes from the calculus of variations. I'm sorry if this problem has trivial answers since my field is somewhat far away from algebraic topology. Many thanks!

Comment: If one had a closed aspherical manifold with this property, then its fundamental group could not contain a Baumslag-Solitar subgroup; such a group has a subgroup with non-trivial $H_2$. Examples of groups that do not contain Baumslag-Solitar subgroups are hyperbolic groups. However, Gromov has conjectured that hyperbolic groups contain a surface subgroup, and hence would have a subgroup with non-trivial $H_2$ if that conjecture is true. 
Moreover, until recently a group of finite type which was non hyperbolic and contained no Baumslag-Solitar subgroup was not known.arxiv.org/abs/2105.14795

Comment: A weak version of what you ask for: There is a closed aspherical $16$-dimensional manifold $M$ such that every finitely-sheeted coverings $\bar M$ of $M$ has finite $H_i(\bar  M)$ for $i=1,2,3$. Here $M$ is any closed Cayley hyperbolic manifold, see section 8 in "Nonarithmetic Superrigid Groups: Counterexamples to Platonov's Conjecture" by Bass and Lubotzky, https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0005302.pdf.

Comment: I am quite sure that no such examples are known.

Comment: What’s the condition for $v\geq 2$?

Comment: @IanAgol: which subgroup do you have in mind for the solvable Baumslag—Solitar groups? The finite-sheeted covers have trivial $H_2$, as does the infinite cyclic cover. (I mean with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, of course.)

Comment: Please, check the correctness of my edit.

Comment: @hjrw: the question asks for trivial homology with finite coefficients as well.

Comment: @IanAgol: Ah, OK. (There’s a typo in that part of the question, so it’s somewhat unclear.)  I’m still a little worried about BS(1,2)…

Comment: @HJRW: It contains $BS(1,4)$, thus, is not a problem.

Comment: It will be a wasted bounty.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Of course, thanks for resolving my worries!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the answer to this question is unknown in general. If one had a closed aspherical manifold with this property, then it could not contain a [Baumslag-Solitar subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group?wprov=sfti1) since such a group has a subgroup with non-trivial $H_2$ (possibly with finite field coefficients, eg $BS(1,2)$ contains a $BS(1,4)$ subgroup with $H_2(BS(1,4);\mathbb{F}_3)\neq 0$). Examples of groups that do not contain Baumslag-Solitar subgroups are [hyperbolic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group?wprov=sfti1). However, Gromov has conjectured that hyperbolic groups contain a surface subgroup, and hence would have a subgroup with non-trivial $H_2$ if that conjecture is true.

Moreover, [until recently](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.14795) a group of finite type (such as the fundamental group of an aspherical manifold) which was non hyperbolic and contained no Baumslag-Solitar subgroup was not known.
Thus I would argue that there is probably no example of this sort in the literature, since it would have resolved one of two possible well-known open questions.

On the other hand, maybe it is known that any aspherical n-manifold admits a cover with non-trivial $H_2$? I think a theorem of this sort in the literature for $n>3$ would be well-known if it existed (and at least @MoisheKohan and myself are not aware of such a theorem, if that carries any weight).